# Power set of $X$ is not in $X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove or find a counterexample to: $P(X) \notin X$.

I think it's true but I'm having trouble coming up with a proof, clearly if $P(X) \in X$ then $X \in P(X) \in X$ but I'm not sure where the contradiction comes from. Does it require well-foundedness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This requires well-foundedness of the $\in$ relation. And that's exactly where the contradiction comes from. $\{X,\mathcal P(X)\}$ has no $\in$-minimal element.

It is consistent, however, that the axiom of foundation fails, and there is some $X$ such that $\mathcal P(X)\in X$. Note that it ***does not*** imply $\mathcal P(X)\subseteq X$, of course, since Cantor's theorem still holds.

Comment: Can I prove this by the way I mentioned in the comments?

Comment: No, for two reasons. It is not hard to construct a set where for every $y\in X$, $\{y\}\in X$ as well. And also because it has nothing to do with whether or not $X\cap\mathcal P(X)=\varnothing$, that would show that $\mathcal P(X)\nsubseteq X$ but nothing about the membership relation.

Comment: Oh okay thanks.